# $.when(...).done(...) in .each()-loop seems to be asynchronous...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, .when

I'm currently trying to go away from AJAX's deprecated `async: false` option by refactoring it for the use of `$.when(...).done(...)`. So far the structure looks like this:

```
$.when($(...).each(function() {
    $.when($.ajax({
        ...
    }),$.ajax({
        ...
    }),$.ajax({
        ...
    })).done(function() {   //function A
        // run as soon as all three AJAX requests in this loop are finished
    });
})).done(function() {   //function B
    // run as soon as $.when().done() of each loop is finished
});
```

So basically I want to have an `.each()`-loop which asynchronously runs three independent AJAX requests and the code in function A after all requests are finished. This part works so far.

The problem now is that I want to have the code in function B executed as soon as the `.each()`-loop is finished, which means that all AJAX requests and function A for every loop should have already been executed before function B is reached. But it seems that `$.when(...).done(...)` inside the loop runs asynchronous itself, thus the `.each()`-loop finishes before the inner `$.when(...).done(...)`-function does, executing function B too early. Is there any way I can work around this problem?

Comment: What you can do is that you return the promise in each iteration of the loop (or push the promise to an array). You evaluate that array using `$.when.apply(null, <array>)`, so that you know all the AJAX calls are completed before you call function B.

Answer (score 0):

So I basically solved it like this:

```
var promises = [];
$(...).each(function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    promises.push(deferred.promise());
    $.when($.ajax({
        ...
    }),$.ajax({
        ...
    }),$.ajax({
        ...
    })).done(function() { //function A
        ...
        deferred.resolve();
    });
});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {   //function B
    ...
});
```

At the beginning of each iteration I'm initializing a Deferred object and push its Promise object into an array. Each time function A is passed the respective Deferred object gets resolved. Function B runs as soon as every Promise in the array is resolved. So basically, Function B will run as soon as function A has been finished for every execution. Works like a charm for me.